# SQL Statement for more than one type of code in the same column

Tags: sql

I have a basic query where I am selecting from one table and joining to another table.  On the second table I am using a filter on a column to exclude records I don't want.

The first table is basic, things like name, ID, address, etc.  It contains no duplicates.  The second table (product table) is more like this:

```
    ID      Code    DESC            Desc2
    -----------------------------------------
    94      PG      County Code     SYDNEY, NE
    95      PG      County Code     MONTICELLO, UT  
    96      PG      County Code     VERNAL, UT  
    97      PG      County Code     OTHER, OUT OF STATE
            PG      County Code     NO DATA 
    1       PS      Race Code       SPANISH AMERICAN    
    2       PS      Race Code       OTHER - WHITE   
    3       PS      Race Code       BLACK   
    4       PS      Race Code       AMERICAN INDIAN
```

And my select looks something like this:

```
Select A.*, B.DESC 
from CustTable A 
INNER JOIN Prod_Table B 
  ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.Code = 'PG'
```

I also have a need to get the records from the Prod_Table where Code = 'PS'.

Is there a way to do this in one query or do I need to make another table with the 'PS' records and query that?

EDIT:  sorry for being too confusing, I was trying to simplify things but that made it worse.  I just edited the post with actual data from the table, maybe this will help.

Comment: Do you want to return the rows that have both `PS` and `PG`?

Comment: Yes.  I also corrected something in my OP, the ID column may be duplicated.

Comment: Based on the sample data what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: If I filter on PG using a where clause, I know I will only get those records.  So far, that has been accurate.  But I have a new requirement where I need to also match data to the PS records.  That is what I am trying to figure out.  I can get it to work if I break out the PS records into a separate table and do a typical join, those results are accurate.  But I am trying to find a way to avoid making a new table just to do that.  If I had to do that, I'd need to then make ~50 new tables because there are SEVERAL different codes.

Comment: Could you show some data and some results. I believe most are still a little confused on what you have and what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.*, B.DESC 
from CustTable A 
INNER JOIN Prod_Table B 
ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.Code = 'PG' OR B.Code = 'PS'
```

OR

```
Select A.*, B.DESC 
from CustTable A 
INNER JOIN Prod_Table B 
ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.Code IN('PG','PS')
```

Comment: I think you meant to use an OR in the first example ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select A.*, B.DESC 
from CustTable A 
INNER JOIN Prod_Table B 
  ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.Code = 'PG' or B.code = 'PS'
```